# Select + update query in the same table

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb, sql-update

I am using MariaDB and I am trying to create a query that updates the boolean column `is_popular` of my photos table, called `Pics`.

To find out which photos are "popular", I pick the top 10 from the entire table. Then, I would like those top 10 photos to set as `true` the `is_popular` field.

The way I could think of to do it was like this:

```
UPDATE Pics 
SET is_popular=true 
WHERE id=(
   SELECT p.id 
   FROM Pics p 
   WHERE p.approved=true 
   ORDER BY p.points 
   DESC LIMIT 10);
```

But I get an error like this:
`ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`

How should I create the query?

Comment: What happens if you do `WHERE id IN (...`?

Comment: How often do you plan to run this UPDATE?

Comment: If I do an `WHERE id IN (...` , an error appears: `ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: Create a view instead. Will always be up-to-date.

Comment: I don't want a view. I have a scheduler in Java that will run this and others updates every X hours

Comment: Multiple-table UPDATE syntax must be used. Or at least use `IN` operator instead of `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `INNER JOIN` :

```
UPDATE Pics p
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id 
   FROM Pics
   WHERE approved=true 
   ORDER BY points DESC 
   LIMIT 10
) as s on s.id = p.id
SET is_popular=true;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z-ajJZMI)

Answer (score 4):

Both *MySQL* and *MariaDB* support `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses for *single-table* updates. So you can write your query just as simple as:

```
UPDATE Pics 
SET is_popular = true 
WHERE approved = true 
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT 10
```